# Why BOOL in Windows is of type int?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Why not defining `BOOL` as an `enum` like in :

```
enum BOOL {FALSE, TRUE};
```

Is there any reason why `BOOL` must be specified **explicitly** as `int` (or any other integral type)?

Comment: Fun fact: There are [WINAPI functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) that return BOOL, but the return value must be checked for zero, non-zero, and -1.

Comment: I think the correct question is "Why `BOOL` is `int` and not `short` or `unsigned short`". Don't think that `enum` is better - this is not Pascal nor C++.

Comment: @nwellnhof http://i.imgur.com/oxDZEVz.jpg

Comment: @i486, better yet, `char`. No need for 16 or 32 bits to say true or false.

Comment: The genius who down-voted me, would you say why? did you know @Remy Lebeau answer?  
My question raised another interesting question, which is why int and not char for example, did you know why?

Comment: It is my understanding that manipulating a `char` can be significantly less efficient than manipulating an `int`.  Any performance gain would be negligible nowadays (except perhaps in a few edge cases) but that wasn't always true.  And I guess some compilers might also complain about loss of precision when converting a boolean result to a character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Raymond Chen's blog article on this topic:

[BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. bool](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923)

> Still more ways of saying the same thing. Why so many?
>
> Because each was invented by different people at different times to solve different problems.
>
> **`BOOL` is the oldest one**. Its definition is simply
>
> `typedef int BOOL;`
>
> **The C programming language uses "int" as its boolean type, and Windows 1.0 was written back when C was the cool language for systems programming**.

The vast majority of the Win32 API is still designed for C to this day, so that it is compatible with a large variety of programming languages that are compatible with C.

Enums have portability issues across compilers, related to differences in byte size and bit representation. Besides, `enum` wasn't added to C until ANSI C in 1989 (aka C98), which was after three releases of Windows (1.0 in 1985, 2.0 in 1987, and 2.1 in 1988), and enums are effectively equivalent to integers anyway.

Comment: That's an interesting question here, though, why wasn't it typedef'd to a `char` to have it signed on 1 byte instead of 2 (or 4) ?

Comment: @Ra'Jiska making it a `char` wouldn't be very beneficial because it would still get promoted to `int` in comparisons and such.

Comment: @RemyLebeau even if compared against another char?

Comment: @BiteBytes Comparison operators usually promote values to int before evaluating the values.

Comment: Is there anything Win API related that can't be answered by citing Raymond? Probably not much... ;)

Comment: The link should be updated to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that C originally had no bool type. As per the C Language Specification, any non-zero integral value evaluates to true and 0 evaluates to false. The BOOL typedef was a later addition by Microsoft for the programming of Windows. The enum would still be evaluated under the covers to 0 and 1 (or something else depending on the machine).