# Using an enum as a parameter and a return type in a function in C

Tags: c, function, enums

If I decided to use an enum, such as this one:

```
typedef enum {
    FALSE, TRUE = !FALSE
} bool;
```

as a parameter, and a return type in this function:

```
bool foo(bool param)
{
    <do something>
    return TRUE;
}
```

Would it cause any problems? for example, across compilers.

PS: I don't intend to use `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: I guess it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It would clash with other code that did `#include <stdbool.h>`. Also different compilers may give different result for `sizeof(bool)`

Comment: @M.M I updated my question, thank's

Comment: You don't intend to, but what if you use external libraries or if other people contribute to your project?  I would recommend using `#include <stdbool.h>` yourself

Comment: @M.M that's actually not the real problem, I can change names, the problem is the notion of using enums as return types and as parameters.

Comment: enums are part of the language. Why would it be a problem to use them?

Comment: @interjay from this post : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863907/why-bool-in-windows-is-of-type-int  
I quote: "Enums have portability issues across compilers, related to differences in byte size and bit representation."

Comment: @BiteBytes That's only an issue if your code makes assumptions about the size or bit representation of the enum.

Comment: Since `c99` you can use built-in type `_Bool`.

Comment: If all your code is compiled with a single compiler (including libraries) and with similar configurations, you should be fine.

Comment: @interjay one question please, concerning the parameters pushed on the stack, the type of `enum` is not necessarily an `int`, indeed, it's just big enough to hold and `int`, so what if one compiler chose to use an `int`, while another chose a `long`, and as you know `int` and `long` are not necessarily the same size. In this case the stack would be corrupted.

Comment: Note that the lengthy `__bool_true_false_are_defined` define is part of the [standard stdbool.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html), so you can at least throw a compile error if this is already defined. I would also use `stdbool.h`, I don't see any reason why not (especially since `true` and `false` are plain macros in `stdbool.h`, and you seem to be concerned with enum portability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't intend to `#include <stdbool.h>` (which might cause conflicts), there should not be a problem with your approach.

---

However, if this is a big project, where others contribute too, then I wouldn't recommend you to go on with your approach, because they might include that header. Moreover, if you decide to use that code in a future project of yours, I am pretty sure that would not remember that detail with this prevention of including that header, except if you document it nicely.

Comment: one question please, concerning the parameters pushed on the stack, the type of `enum` is not necessarily an `int`, indeed, it's just big enough to hold and `int`, so what if one compiler chose to use an `int`, while another chose a `long`, and as you know `int` and `long` are not necessarily the same size. In this case the stack would be corrupted.

Comment: The stack wouldn't be corrupted in this case?

Comment: But you would use one compiler.

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: In my question I mentioned "across compilers" issue.

Comment: Different compilers could choose different sizes for `int` and `long` and a whole bunch of other things, too, so this potential problem is not specific to `enum`s. On the other hand, for a modern architecture like x86_64 you're overwhelmingly likely to be passing parameters and return values for enumeration types in registers, not on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this is only an example and your actual type names will not collide with something "standard'. Using enum types as parameters and return values is 100% OK and safe.